# Inserting the count value in a column of table

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

I have two tables , one which has a list of points and an other  which has a list of polygons. I am finding out that how many points lie in each polygon. I hope I have find the count(*) but I am not sure how I can insert it to a new row called total_num in the table:

So here is for example . Table 1- points , Table2 - poly.

points as the_geom column with all the points geometric data and
poly has an id,geom column with all the polygon geometric data.

I was able to find the toatl_num(number of points inside each polygon) using:

```
select count(*) as total 
from points, poly 
where st_contains(poly.geom,points.the_geom) 
group by poly.id;
```

I am grouping them based on Id(unique in poly table). I hope this is right(please comment if it is not correct). Now how can I take this total and insert it into a column called total_num in table poly?

I tried this:

```
update poly 
set total_num=select count(*) as total 
from points, poly 
where st_contains(poly.geom,points.the_geom)
group by poly.id;
```

Table - point:

```
the_geom
---------
 0101000020D708000000000000E8282F4100000000F0BB0D41
 0101000020D7080000000000006C892E410000000040170341
 0101000020D7080000000000003EB82F4100000000A8660641
 0101000020D708000000000000FA792E4100000000D01A0641
 0101000020D708000000000000821F2F410000000028500841
 0101000020D70800000000000004A32F4100000000B8B90241



Table - poly
------------

id  | geom | total_num

1   |(geom consist of geometrical representation of polygon
2   | which can not be entered here because its too long)
3   |
4   |
5   |
6   |
```

but this gives me an error!
Thanks

Comment: Yes, create a column named as totalnum in table poly and then use UPDATE statement to update the count of each poly as per their poly.id

Comment: but it doest'nt work. i get an error saying - more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

Comment: You need to apply join and condition in join should be p1.id equal to p2.id where p1 and p2 are alias for poly table. Use google to check Update statement with join.

Comment: Using onlypostgresql, I tagged the other thinking the syntax might closely resemble

Comment: Any comments on this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `INNER Join` instead of `Subquery`.

```
UPDATE poly 
SET    total_num=B.total 
FROM  (        SELECT   Count(*) AS total ,poly.ID
                FROM     points, 
                         poly 
                WHERE    St_contains(poly.geom,points.the_geom) 
                GROUP BY poly.id) B 
where poly.id = B.id
```

Comment: It gives an error saying column b.id does not exist

Comment: @johnmathew I added ID in the query check now.

Comment: I get - table "a" is specified more than once

Comment: @johnmathew Which DBMS you are using Mysql or SQL server

Comment: I am using postgresql

Comment: It executed, but I get same value updated for each row. All the rows have same value as 158 now.

Comment: @johnmathew Then all your Id's are same in poly table. Add some sample data so that it will be easy to write the required query.

Comment: I don't have a column called id in points table. I only have it in poly table. Is tats the reason?

Comment: @johnmathew No that is not the reason. Add sample data of both tables in the question.

Comment: Isnt that join could be done only if two table have a common column? Is it possible if the result could be shared to view and then moved to poly table?

Comment: Any comments on this?

Comment: You have accepted the answer. What comments are you expecting, other than this looks like yet another of last week's homework extravaganza, which featured a very similar question.